# Why I can't get contents of addressbook

Tags: ios

I am trying to get content of addressbook with these codes.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook =
ABAddressBookCreate();

if (addressBook != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Succesful.");


    NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray
                            *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    NSUInteger i = 0;
    NSLog(@"countT=%lu",(unsigned long)[allContacts count]);
}
```

I get Succesful log but count is always "0", I use simulator for this and I added contacts in it for test. It is iOS 7 and Xcode 5.

Comment: by the way i have #import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your test for nil is meaningless. If you have not been granted access by the user to the address book, the result of `ABAddressBookCreate()` will still be non-nil. But it will be useless!

So, the moral is: always test properly to see whether you have been granted access (`ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus`) and, if access has been neither granted nor denied, request it formally (`ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion`).

Comment: See for example https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch18p713addressBook/ch31p973addressBook/ViewController.m